# Can I set LESS variable to CSS property value?

Tags: less

I want to set a LESS variable (@primary) to the background-color of an existing CSS class (.layer).

**Background**: This is in a library called Core. Several apps that use Core provide their own theme by overriding the background color of .layer via CSS. I want to add @primary and use that elsewhere in Core but I need it set to the app-specific theme color. I could modify every app to override @primary but that is not practical so I was looking for a way to access that color from the already overridden .layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you right, this is what you are doing:

1. Use less to create Core.css in the Core project. The output is Core.css.
2. Include Core.css (through npm or cdn...) into a separate project, let's call it ChildApp, that does not have access to the Core less variables
3. ChildApp is overriding some of the css from Core.css with their own css.

If this is the case, then no, there is no way for you to directly modify the child's overrides from the parent.

The closest thing would be to change the html structure or class names from Core.css so that the child overrides would no longer have any effect on the items in core you wish to tweak from Core.

Comment: That's almost exactly what I was trying to do. Your explanation has helped me see how I was thinking about this wrong (first attempt at using LESS). I was hoping to grab the override values provided by ChildApp and apply them elsewhere in Core. I was forgetting that LESS is a PRE-processor and is out of the picture (leaving me with plain CSS in Core) by the time ChildApp performs its overrides. Thanks.